# SQL Subquery join/group by/having

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, subquery

I'm trying to write a subquery for an e-mail marketing project, with two tables (and the columns I need) below:

```
Table: Email_Send:
Column: E-mail_ID
Column: Subject_Line
Column: Send_Date

Table: Email_Event:
Column: Email_ID
Column: Recipient_ID
Column: Recipient_Name
Column: Event_Type
```

I'm trying to return Recipient_Name, Count of the Event_Types = "Click", Subject_Line, and Send_Date.

I've gotten the inner query to work perfectly:

```
SELECT     Email_Event.Recipient_ID, 
           Email_Send.Email_ID, 
           COUNT(Email_Event.Event_Type) 
FROM       Email_Send 
INNER JOIN Email_Event ON Email_Send.Email_ID = Email_Event.EmailID
WHERE      (Email_Event.Event_Type = 'Click') 
AND        (Email_Send.Send_Date > GETDATE() - 3)
GROUP BY   Email_Event.Recipient_ID, Email_Send.Email_ID                      
HAVING     (COUNT(Email_Event.Event_Type) > 4))
```

This returns three columns, the Recipient_ID, Email_ID, and Count of Event_Types.  I have to use Recipient_ID and Email_ID as opposed to Recipient_Name and Email_Line in case duplicates.

I've tried multiple subqueries, but how can I add Recipient_Name, Subject_Line, and Send_Date to get returned along with Count(Event_Type)?

Comment: GETDATE() is a MS SQL Server function. Yet, you've tagged this question `mysql`. Can you clarify what server you're trying to use?

Comment: My apologies, I am indeed using MS SQL Server.

Comment: could you give sample data and query result expected from that sample data?

Comment: Certainly.  In the Email_Send field, every time an email it sent, it logs the email ID (primary key; int): [864451], the subject line (varchar): ['Save 50% Off your next purchase'], and send date [1/8/14 12:00pm].  The email_event table logs every time an event (click; open; unsubscribe) occurs.  email_id (foreign key to email send), email_event: [Click], recipient ID (primary key): [1561123] recipient name [John Smith].  I want to return subject line, name, email send date, and count of clicks when email event type is click, and occurs more than 4 times for a recipient ID and by email ID.